# Unity: NavMesh Agent custom movement instead of basic transform position

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I want my navMesh agent to perform a custom action , such as jumping, towards the target. I checked some tutorials and everybody does .setDestination and the agent moves towards it , what I would like is to add my own custom movement for agent to perform towards the destnation point.

for example: I'd like the movement towards the destionation to be done using addForce(100,100,0,) until it reaches the destination.

example picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgPIY.jpg

Comment: Surely if you want a custom action, you link up the animation to do that custom action instead of say "walk" or "run"

Comment: @BugFinder but I want it to do an addForce not an animation . I want it to interact with physics because I want to change it slightly at every iteration of the addForce.

Comment: Then add force..